# How do I get wi-fi to work on my iMac G5?

Tags: macosx

I have an iMac G5 model 8,7 with AirForce One 54g Broadcom BCM4318 wi-fi but it doesn't work, the wireless menu tells me that the firmware is missing.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.1 for powerpc64.

Please help, I really need it to work!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to fix this on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

In my case, because jockey-gtk always crashes, I had to also install the firmware-b43-installer because I couldn't activate the driver from System Settings.

Depending on what wireless card you have you choose from that list.

In my case the commands were:

sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter

and

sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

Reboot and works perfectly ever since!!!